# select first rows of grouped dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6], 
                   list('AABBBCDEEEFFFF'), 
                   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
                   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,11,12,11,11,11]]).T
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']

df
Out[4]: 
   col1 col2 col3 col4
0     1    A    1    1
1     1    A    2    2
2     2    B    3    3
3     2    B    4    4
4     2    B    5    5
5     3    C    6    6
6     4    D    7    7
7     5    E    8    8
8     5    E    9    9
9     5    E   10   11
10    6    F   11   12
11    6    F   12   11
12    6    F   13   11
13    6    F   14   11
```

that I group according to its columns in the following order

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).size()

Out[7]: 
col1  col2  col3
1     A     1       1
            2       1
2     B     3       1
            4       1
            5       1
3     C     6       1
4     D     7       1
5     E     8       1
            9       1
            10      1
6     F     11      1
            12      1
            13      1
            14      1
```

How can I extract the first value of col3 for each group of the resulting dataframe?

```
df_return
Out[4]: 
   col3
0     1
1     3
2     6
3     7
4     8
5     11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('col3').drop_duplicates(['col1','col2']).col3
Out[1258]: 
0      1
2      3
5      6
6      7
7      8
10    11
Name: col3, dtype: object
```

Or you can adding `groupby` after `group` `size`

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).size().groupby(level=[0,1]).head(1)
Out[1260]: 
col1  col2  col3
1     A     1       1
2     B     3       1
3     C     6       1
4     D     7       1
5     E     8       1
6     F     11      1
dtype: int64
```

To get the value

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).size().groupby(level=[0,1]).head(1).index.get_level_values(2)
Out[1261]: Int64Index([1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11], dtype='int64', name='col3')
```